# How do you handle a 401 error when using willSendRequestForAuthenticationChallenge?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, authentication, nsurlconnection

I'm using Apple's preferred method for dealing with NTLM authentication challenges through NSURLConnection via willSendRequestForAuthenticationChallenge. I'm trying to determine how to deal with situations where the challenge essentially fails (such as if the user's password had changed or this is the first time the user has ever made a web service request from their device) and now the application needs to handle obtaining the new password and retrying the URL request.

But, I'm stuck.

Here's what I'm trying to do. In doing some basic testing, I first wipe out the credentials storage so that I can pretend as if this is the user's first time making a request to a URL that needs to be authenticated. I call using [challenge performDefaultHandlingForAuthenticationChallenge] which I would expect to fail in some way since there's no credentials yet in storage. Well, I unexpectedly get a response back in didReceiveData which has the 401 authentication error buried in the HTML response string; however it's disguised as data received from my URL (web service request). If I make a subsequent call and observe [challenge previousFailureCount], it's still at 0 (and I think I know why; I still don't have any credentials saved in the credential storage).

How do I deal with the 401 error properly without having to parse the response data? I would think a 401 would have automatically been recognized by the NSURLConnection and allow me to see it some way.